# Floating point issue. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Basically my question is: Why do I get value as 130.00000000000003 instead of 130.0 ?

I just outputted everything that goes under the hood and hope it's clear enough. I know it's most likely the string/float is what causing this but i am not sure how to solve it.

I have tried parseFloat() , parseFloat().toFixed(1) , parseFloat().round(1) but still I keep getting that .00000000000003. Not always, but sometimes.

**Code :**

```
// ... 'cost' will be passed as a parameter to the function 

 totalBudget = parseFloat(document.getElementById('currentBudget').value);// e.g value ='4' 

 ni = parseFloat(totalBudget);
 cost = (cost).toFixed(1);
 alert("totalBudget " + totalBudget + "\nni " + ni + "\ncost " + cost);
 ni += parseFloat(cost);
 alert("ni " + ni);

 alert('\nni= ' + ni + '\ntotalBudget= ' + totalBudget + '\ncost=' + cost);

 var playerCost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('playerCost' + vTemp).value);
 playerCost = (playerCost).toFixed(1);
 alert('playerCost= ' + playerCost);
 alert('\nNow will subtract ');
 ni -= playerCost;
 alert('\nAfter Subtraction');
 alert('\nni= ' + ni + '\nplayerCost= ' + playerCost);


alert('-------'+
'\ncurrBudget= '+totalBudget+
'\nnew budget ni= '+ni+
'\nPlayer#:vTemp= '+vTemp+
'\nCurr player cost= '+playerCost+
'\nNew players cost= '+cost +
"\nParseFloat(playerCost)for curr player= "+parseFloat(playerCost));
```

**Output:**

```
 // If cost = 7.2 and playerCost= 7.1. Notice all floating values are super fine. 
    totalBudget 129.8
    ni 129.8
    cost 7.2

    totalBudget 129.8
    ni 129.8
    cost 7.2


    ni= 137
    totalBudget= 129.8
    cost=7.2

    plaerCost= 7.1

    Now will subtract 
    After Subtraction


    ni= 129.9
    playerCost= 7.1


    -------
    currBudget= 129.8
    new budget ni= 129.9
    Player#:vTemp= 8
    Curr player cost= 7.1
    New players cost= 7.2
    ParseFloat(playerCost)for curr player= 7.1
```

Without refreshing the page, I do some other operation on the website

**Output:**

```
// If cost = 7.3 and playerCost= 7.2. Notice floating points are totally not fine. 
totalBudget 129.9
ni 129.9
cost 7.3

ni 137.20000000000002

ni= 137.20000000000002
totalBudget= 129.9
cost=7.3

plaerCost= 7.2

Now will subtract 

After Subtraction

ni= 130.00000000000003
playerCost= 7.2

-------
currBudget= 129.9
new budget ni= 130.00000000000003
Player#:vTemp= 8
Curr player cost= 7.2
New players cost= 7.3
ParseFloat(playerCost)for curr player= 7.2
```

Then I will get "Over budget. Please change your players!" error cause 130.00000000000003 > 130.0

Comment: Not sure, but the advice I live by is when fractional decimals matter use integer emulation not raw floating point -- ESPECIALLY IN JAVASCRIPT since you have to worry not only about differences in hardware but also differences in the javascript engine.

Comment: A useful insight into floating point problems http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: No, your approach is fine (notice that IE has some bugs in `toFixed`). Yet be sure to apply `parseFloat` only on strings and use `toFixed` *after* you determined the result, not before

Comment: @Bergi They said the approach was fine in the floating point math on the Ariane 5 rocket and in the Patriot misses systems also... look how they turned out. Any time you cant accept errors in decimals like in graphics or video rendering, you should really use decimal emulation with integers not FPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an overkill for this, but try [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js). Floating points are not good for precision math, and javascript has no built in "decimal" type to handle it.

Also if precision is not that big of an issue, try the [toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) method. It will just cut off the parts you don't need.

```
var a = 1.000000000000005;
var b = a.toPrecision(6); //returns a string
var c = parseFloat(b); //returns a number
alert(b); // shows 1.000000;
alert(c); // shows 1;
```

EDIT: Actually you should be fine with

```
function roundFloat(input, prec) {
    return parseFloat(input.toFixed(prec));
}
```

and use it on the numbers in need of rounding.

Comment: So the idea is, to put toFixed() inside parseFloat(). Wow, that totally slipped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Attempts to do "money math" with (binary) floating point in **any** programming language are doomed to such a fate. Floating point involves binary fractions, not decimal fractions, and so there will be such anomalies introduced inevitably.

Note that `toFixed()` converts a floating point number to a string. It doesn't really help much.

*edit* — a comment correctly points out that floating point formats are not necessarily *binary* floating point formats. I think old IBM mainframes (maybe current z-series machines for all I know) used a base-16 exponent and (maybe) base-16 mantissas. Nowadays, however, IEEE-754 format is (for good or ill) pretty universal, and it's the format used by x86 machines.  GPUs aren't (necessarily; I think the 32-bit NVidia floating point is pretty close) all IEEE-754 but all the ones I know of are binary floating point systems. (And, specifically, JavaScript is binary floating point by definition of the language.)

*edit again* — Eric Postpischil schools me in the comments below :-)

Comment: I have seen a few examples where rounding was solved by number -> string -> number conversion in javascript. toFixed() can be used for the first step.

Comment: “Floating point” does not mean binary. It means the conceptual location of the radix point is variable, usually determined by an exponent value in the encoding. While binary floating point is the most common, there are decimal floating-point implementations, so it is inaccurate to state that “money math” is doomed in any programming language. (However, even with decimal floating point, one must take care about non-representable values introduce in various ways, such as dividing annual interest rates into monthly rates, apportioning values to shares, and so on.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes that is correct, but in 2012 I think it's vastly more likely that one has to cope with binary floating point versus anything else.  I will amend the answer however because your point is valid.

Comment: It is IEEE 754, not 794. And IEEE 754-2008 defines both binary floating point and decimal floating point. This is not ancient history; IBM produces machines with decimal floating point in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one significant decimal place, multiply with 10, truncate to integer and compare that:

```
var budget = 130.00000000000003;
var c1 = Math.round(budget * 10);
var c2 = Math.round(130 * 10);

if (c1 > c2)
    do_something;
```